# Erro no bind_param. Data too long for column

Tags: php

Estou com o seguinte erro

> Erro: Data too long for column 'opcoes' at row 1

Esse é meu código:

```
$arr = Array();

foreach($_POST['opcoes'] AS $n=> $m) {
    $p = explode("|", $m);
    $arr[] = $p[1]."-".$_POST['opcoes'][$n];
    $i++;
}
$opcoes = implode(",", $arr);



$rs = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela (nome1,nome2,opcoes) VALUES (?,?,?)");

$rs->bind_param('sss', $_POST['nome1'], $_POST['nome2'], $opcoes);
```

Como corrigir esse erro?

Comment: Está no erro: Dados grande para a coluna! Aumente a coluna ou diminua quantidade de caracteres.